# The string should be displayed only if flag is true, but the flag gets added to the string if it is false

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a string based on a flag value

```
return `${super.getDetails()} Electric: ${this.isElectric} ${flag && '|hatchback'}`;
```

This displays - `2014 Chevy Malibu Electric: false false` if flag is false

I want it to display `2014 Chevy Malibu Electric: false`

```
return `${super.getDetails()} Electric: ${this.isElectric} ${flag && '|hatchback'}`;
```

This displays the perfect answer if flag is true

```
2014 Chevy Malibu Electric: false |hatchback
```

Code tried:
    When flag is false,
    return `${super.getDetails()} Electric: ${this.isElectric} ${flag && '|hatchback'}`;

Expected:

```
2014 Chevy Malibu Electric: false
```

Actual:

```
2014 Chevy Malibu Electric: false false
```

Comment: `${false && whatever}` is always going to return false.  It's behaving as expected.

Comment: What is the alternative?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a variable instead of a literal `false` or `true`?

Comment: `${ variable ? '|hatchback' : '' }` this will do the trick

Comment: are you also expecting something like 'this.isHatchback', if yes you can use this.isHatchback? "hatchback" : "" . It is not clear how you are deciding to include hatchback in you result.

Comment: You could just add `|| ''` to it, `flag && '|hatchback' || ''`, though I prefer the ternary for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary rather than logical operator, so you can return an empty string when it's false.

```
return `${super.getDetails()} Electric: ${this.isElectric} ${false ? '|hatchback' : ''}`;

return `${super.getDetails()} Electric: ${this.isElectric} ${true ? '|hatchback' : ''}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate `flag && |hatchback` in the placeholder of a template literal (`${flag && '|hatchback'}`) it will inevitably print the value of your flag variable or `|hatchback`. Instead of using `&&` operator use a ternary operator like this:

```
return `${super.getDetails()} Electric: ${this.isElectric} ${flag ? '|hatchback': ''}`;
```